# How to count the days Starting from current date?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a day counter inside my app. How display a real-time day counter means the user can see when every second, minute, hours and day changes. And if the user decides to stop the counter, I want to store the total number of days the counter counts.
I have got the flutter package, which is a day countdown package. What they did is accept the end date and count down, but I want the reverse, which means count up the day starting from DateTime.now() until the user stops it.

Comment: Check this: https://pub.dev/packages/stop_watch_timer

Comment: You can use moment for this

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible approaches you can take...

The Timer class
or AnimationBuiler

check this repo for an example
https://github.com/John-Daniels/flutter_countdown_app